# Selecting one features out of Event Layer is selecting more then one feature

Tags: arcgis-pro, select

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.8.2. With the "Make XY Event Layer" I am making a Layer out of a table in our sde.

After creating this layer I want to select one specific feature from it, but then other features are also selected. If a feature from a FC is selected this does not happen.

Is this a known problem and is there a way to solve this in any other way, except in creating a FC out of the event layer?

Edit:

Inside the event layer, I select one feature with a Rectangle (in the Image the feature with the red arrow). From the same event layer more than this one Feature will be selected.

[image]

Comment: How are you selecting them?

Comment: I am selecting them with a Polygon. If I use "Select by Attributes" on a specific ID the same happens.

Comment: Other features are getting selected, can you specify this? Do you mean if other features that are there in the contents are getting selected? Share a few screenshots explaining the behavior.

Comment: whats the coordinate system of your points and this polygon layer?

Comment: @YogeshChavan I edited my Question

Comment: I don't know the solution but FYI I've seen this behavior with event layers, so it's not just you. It also happens when using the Identify tool: clicking one point gives results from many points. Converting the event layer to a feature class resolves it, but that doesn't help if you need to keep it as an event layer.

Comment: @Hornbydd I do not use a polygon layer for selection. I use the select tool and there i use a rectangle. I also tried with Select by Attributes, but with the same results.
The coordinate system is EPSG: 25832

Comment: Is the map also in UTM zone 32N?

Comment: @Hornbydd yes it is

Comment: Can you share your data to see if others can replicate the issue?

Comment: @hornbydd The problem seems to be with our Oracle database. If I export the table to a gdb and make the event layer from the copy it works as it should.